# Is there an equivalent of Control Flow Guard for Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, threat-mitigation, microsoft

Introduced by Microsoft in recent versions of Windows and its compilers, Control Flow Guard is a useful defence in depth measure in the mitigation of return-oriented programming exploits.

My question is, is there any equivalent of this available or planned on any other operating system and compiler - particularly Linux and GCC?

Comment: IIRC only clang provides a similar technique

Comment: This requires a compatible runtime loader. There are such systems on Linux, coming from app security research. A prominent example that comes to mind is *libdetox* from Mathias Payer. Read his thesis for details: `Safe Loading and Efficient Runtime Confinement: A Foundation for Secure
Execution`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to that there are two possible implementation working in Linux. One is made by grsecurity named: ["Reuse attack Protector (RAP)"](https://grsecurity.net/rap_announce_ret.php). Another is in llvm implemented and calls [control flow integrity  (cfi)](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ControlFlowIntegrity.html). As I understood: CFG is the marketing name of Microsoft for control flow integrity.

The Chrome Team seems to work with that very well.

Most of the information came from [Hanno Böck's](https://hboeck.de/) [Presentation](https://www.int21.de/slides/copenhagensec-cfi). He also provides some more details where CFI/CFG would have helped. 
In addition, you might take a look at [this](https://www.endgame.com/blog/technical-blog/disarming-control-flow-guard-using-advanced-code-reuse-attacks). Just not that you get the impression that this is a silver bullet.

Comment: your endgame post URL has changed, [here](https://www.endgame.com/blog/technical-blog/disarming-control-flow-guard-using-advanced-code-reuse-attacks) is the new URL.

Comment: I updated the URL in respect to your comment. Thank you for keep track of this.

Comment: your informative answer should be respected, not my comment. :D

Answer (score 0):

XGuard from KarambaSecurity is a well tested suite implementing  Control Flow Integrity for Linux on GCC and other build environments

Assaf Harel(Chief Scientist @Karamba Security)